# PSA: PCI bus and Wireless questions

Tags: discussion

Please note that some single-board computers, such as **[Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1107/59404)** and **BeagleBone**, do not have PCI/PCI-e bus. Thus, as observed in [this case](https://askubuntu.com/q/1013682/295286), the [often-cited diagnostic script for wireless](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013682/beaglebone-black-wireless-with-ubuntu-xenial-16-04-wifi-not-working#comment1646033_1013682) may not work properly and installing additional packages intended for PCI bus may not help.

The reason why Raspberry Pi and BeagleBone are highlighted is because there are other development platforms that do support PCI bus. AskUbuntu doesn't have a lot of users who consistently handle [wireless](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wireless) questions, hence this FYI.

Second, I've submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/issues/7) for the diagnostic script, so until it's fixed or if [Wild Man](https://askubuntu.com/users/153297/wild-man) decides it's unnecessary to edit the script behavior, please use discretion when comes to supporting wireless on SBC platforms.

Thanks for cooperation!

Comment: Noted. Possibly helpful observations: The BBBWireless, the subject of the question says it has a *WiLink 1835 WiFi.* An examination here is unclear exactly what the interface is or how to capture it in the ubiquitous wireless script. http://www.ti.com/product/WL1835MOD I note that the driver *wl18xx* is loaded and that one of its dependents is *wlcore_sdio* so it is perhaps related to SDIO.  The wireless script is also unable to find SDIO devices. There is no helpful *lssdio* command that we are aware of that identifies them. So far, we've been relying on `dmesg | grep -i sdio`.

Comment: I see chili555 commented and I have consulted with other knowledgeable wifi experts, also the person that maintains the script these days and to our knowledge there is no commands to do what you want, the script was created for diagnosing wifi issues with computers and these devices at least for the time being is out of the scope of the scripts capabilities. As for hiding the output of like lspci if there is no wifi devices on lspci then it shows "./wireless-info: line 179: lspci: command not found" which is fine in our opinion. Thank you for contacting as but for now we are deferring editing.

Comment: @WildMan It makes sense that the script was created with desktop platforms in mind. I suppose for now those that support wireless questions on SBCs just have to keep in mind there's slight differences. Thank you for the response !